# Why is one function returning an array and the other one an object in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have two Laravel functions that use Eloquent to retreive information from the DB(Postgres) which are virtually the same except that the **where** in one is a **greater or equal than** and the other one is **less than** (dates)

**First function:**

```
events = Event::join('cat_status_event', 'event.status', '=', 'cat_status_event.id_cat_status_event')
            ->join('place', 'event.place', '=', 'place.id_place')
            ->take(50)
            ->get(['event.name','place.name as place', 'cat_status_event.description as status'])
            ->where('start', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

And is returning this response (an array):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Christmas",
        "start": "2020-12-24 17:29:23",
        "status": "OK"
    },
    {
        "name": "Thanksgiving",
        "start": "2021-11-26 01:19:30",
        "status": "OK"
    }
]
```

**And the second function:**

```
events = Event::join('cat_status_event', 'event.status', '=', 'cat_status_event.id_cat_status_event')
            ->join('place', 'event.place', '=', 'place.id_place')
            ->take(50)
            ->get(['event.name','place.name as place', 'cat_status_event.description as status'])
            ->where('start', '<', date('Y-m-d'));
```

And is returning this json (an object):

```
{
    "2": {
        "name": "Birthday",
        "start": "2020-11-21 01:17:07",
        "status": "OK"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Anniversary",
        "start": "2020-11-21 01:17:07",
        "status": "OK"
    }
}
```

I want both functions to return arrays (like the first one), and the only difference between theme is at the **where** statement at the end

Comment: try `->whereDate('start', '<', date('Y-m-d'));` use `whereDate()`

Comment: It says whereDate does not exist. I am using join at the beginning. Will update question with complete function

Comment: How are you returning/printing both query result?

Comment: return $events; I've tried return response()->json($events); but it has the same result. I'm testing them with Postman.

Comment: try removing the last where for both functions, and watch if the results are the same.

Comment: Same result. They are pretty much the same

Comment: Do you do any other operations over the `$events` variable before returning? Are these two functions executed within the same context or are they parts of different actions?

Comment: Both functions are parts of diferent actions. I do not make operations to $events after the code shown.

Comment: Then I guess it could be POSTMAN that is formatting your response.

Comment: I am using Vue to get the data from the Laravel functions and that's how I know it's not only Postman. (I use Postman for testing and have never seen it format responses on it's own)

Comment: We face the same problem a while ago. We had to pass the results through a Laravel Resource to have a constant array formatting. We didn't find any other solution

Comment: You may add `->values()` at the end of second function - it's probably returning an object because the original keys are retained and are not in sequence. Using values() will reset the keys, starting from 0 so it would be in sequence again. Or you can tack on `->values()->all()` on both functions to get the output as array

Comment: @Donkarnash Your suggestion worked. Thank you! They were indeed not in sequence. Adding ->values or ->values()->all() produced the same outpus (array).